# How do I get difference in two timestamp

Tags: php

I am trying to get diffrence in both the timestamp i dont know what i am missing.

parts of my codes here.

```
$newtime = 1368250840;
$oldtime = 1171502725;
$diffrence = $newtime - $oldtime;
echo $diffrence;                   // 196748115 till here its fine
$date = $date->setTimestamp("$diffrence"); // problem here
echo $date->format('H:i:s') . "\n";
```

I try changing it to

```
$date = $date->setTimestamp('$diffrence');
```

and this

```
$date = $date->setTimestamp(' . $diffrence . ');
```

Any solution plz :)
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
$date = new DateTime("@$diffrence");
echo $date->format('H:i:s') . "\n";
```

Or

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp( $diffrence);
echo $date->format('H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`date_diff()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) method!

```
<?php
  $datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
  $datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
  $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
  echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

Comment: we dont have inputs as formated date string. we need to feed timestamps. this wont fit the context.

Comment: Then you can use this solution. :) I see that you have already got a solution. If you feel something simpler, you can use this! :)

Answer (score 0):

Could just use PHP's [`date`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function if you don't need the object.

```
echo date("H:i:s", $diffrence);
```